# grouping values with distinct count of elements

Tags: javascript

Lets I have a data object that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "scenario_id": 238,
    "scenario_desc": "k1204",
    "scenario_status": null,
    "scn_appl_lob_ownr_nm": "Crd",
    "scenario_asv_id": 21216,
    "appl_ci_id": "CI256747",
    "mth_dt": "2015-01",
    "cost_curr": 888.7326,
    "qty_curr": "2",
    "cost_trgt": 0,
    "qty_trgt": "0",
    "ftprnt": [
      "Both"
    ]
  },
  {
    "scenario_id": 238,
    "scenario_desc": "k1204",
    "scenario_status": null,
    "scn_appl_lob_ownr_nm": "Crd",
    "scenario_asv_id": 21216,
    "appl_ci_id": "CI256747",
    "mth_dt": "2015-01",
    "cost_curr": 13479.6678574427,
    "qty_curr": "17",
    "cost_trgt": 0,
    "qty_trgt": "0",
    "ftprnt": [
      "Both"
    ]
  },
  {
    "scenario_id": 238,
    "scenario_desc": "k1204",
    "scenario_status": null,
    "scn_appl_lob_ownr_nm": "Crd",
    "scenario_asv_id": 21216,
    "appl_ci_id": "CI256747",
    "mth_dt": "2015-01",
    "cost_curr": 11295.401684737,
    "qty_curr": "17",
    "cost_trgt": 0,
    "qty_trgt": "0",
    "ftprnt": [
      "Both"
    ]
  },
  {
    "scenario_id": 238,
    "scenario_desc": "k1204",
    "scenario_status": null,
    "scn_appl_lob_ownr_nm": "Crd",
    "scenario_asv_id": 21216,
    "appl_ci_id": "CI256747",
    "mth_dt": "2015-01",
    "cost_curr": 2263.9328,
    "qty_curr": "10",
    "cost_trgt": 0,
    "qty_trgt": "0",
    "ftprnt": [
      "Both"
    ]
  },
  {
    "scenario_id": 238,
    "scenario_desc": "k1204",
    "scenario_status": null,
    "scn_appl_lob_ownr_nm": "Crd",
    "scenario_asv_id": 21215,
    "appl_ci_id": "CI291768",
    "mth_dt": "2015-01",
    "cost_curr": 58406.3066,
    "qty_curr": "17",
    "cost_trgt": 0,
    "qty_trgt": "0",
    "ftprnt": [
      "Cloud"
    ]
  },
  {
    "scenario_id": 178,
    "scenario_desc": "ktest",
    "scenario_status": null,
    "scn_appl_lob_ownr_nm": "Crd",
    "scenario_asv_id": 11028,
    "appl_ci_id": "ASV",
    "mth_dt": "2015-01",
    "cost_curr": 0,
    "qty_curr": "0",
    "cost_trgt": 0,
    "qty_trgt": "0",
    "ftprnt": [
      "Cloud"
    ]
  },
  {
    "scenario_id": 178,
    "scenario_desc": "ktest",
    "scenario_status": null,
    "scn_appl_lob_ownr_nm": "Crd",
    "scenario_asv_id": 11028,
    "appl_ci_id": "ASV",
    "mth_dt": "2015-01",
    "cost_curr": 0,
    "qty_curr": "0",
    "cost_trgt": 0,
    "qty_trgt": "0",
    "ftprnt": [
      "Cloud"
    ]
  },
  {
    "scenario_id": 178,
    "scenario_desc": "ktest",
    "scenario_status": null,
    "scn_appl_lob_ownr_nm": "Crd",
    "scenario_asv_id": 11028,
    "appl_ci_id": "ASV",
    "mth_dt": "2015-01",
    "cost_curr": 2259.994,
    "qty_curr": "6",
    "cost_trgt": 0,
    "qty_trgt": "0",
    "ftprnt": [
      "Cloud"
    ]
  },
  {
    "scenario_id": 178,
    "scenario_desc": "ktest",
    "scenario_status": null,
    "scn_appl_lob_ownr_nm": "Crd",
    "scenario_asv_id": 11028,
    "appl_ci_id": "ASV",
    "mth_dt": "2015-01",
    "cost_curr": 0,
    "qty_curr": "0",
    "cost_trgt": 0,
    "qty_trgt": "0",
    "ftprnt": [
      "Cloud"
    ]
  }
]
```

right now, I can use d3 nest rollup return the sum of cost (cost_curr + cost_trgt) by scenario_desc, ftprnt, and mth_dt like this:

```
var costByScn = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.scenario_desc })
    .key(function(d) { return d.ftprnt })
    .key(function(d) {

        var mth_dt = new Date(d.mth_dt).getTime();
        return mth_dt;
      })
    .rollup(function(v) {

            return parseFloat(d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.cost_curr + d.cost_trgt }))

    })
    .entries(response);
console.log("costByScn: ", JSON.stringify(costByScn));
```

but how would I get the distinct count of appl_ci_id by scenario_desc, ftprnt, and mth_dt? I'm also not limited by using d3 as I can use something such as lodash to do the same thing too...

the end result would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "key": "k1204", 
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "Both", 
        "values": [
          {
            "key": "1420070400000", 
            "values": 1
          }
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "key": "Cloud", 
        "values": [
          {
            "key": "1420070400000", 
            "values": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }, 
  {
    "key": "ktest", 
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "Cloud", 
        "values": [
          {
            "key": "1420070400000", 
            "values": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

here is the code in jsbin as well...

https://jsbin.com/jicuxohawi/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using lodash...

```
var costByScn = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.scenario_desc })
    .key(function(d) { return d.ftprnt })
    .key(function(d) {

        var mth_dt = new Date(d.mth_dt).getTime();
        return mth_dt;
      })
    .rollup(function(v) {

            var z = _.map(v, 'appl_ci_id');
            console.log("z is: ", z)

            var q = _.uniq(z)

            console.log("q is: ", q)
            var len = q.filter(function(val, i, arr) { 
                            return arr.indexOf(val) === i;
                          }).length;
            return len;


    })
    .entries(response);
```